# Unable to install m2w64-libpng using conda

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I ran into an issue while installing anaconda with python 3.7 environment using the anaconda navigator. It showed conda process error ResolvePackageNotFound and a list of packages like 
[image]

while installing conda I also imported a .yml file : 
[image]

When I tried to install one of the packages manually I got the following error

[image]

I also edited the yml file and wrote all the packages that were not found under the **pip** heading. But I encountered the same issue.
I am not sure how to go about resolving this issue.

Comment: That was exported from a Windows machine. Ask whoever can you that YAML to use `conda env export --from-history`, otherwise you have to remove all builds and any platform-specific packages.

Comment: @merv Do you mean the .yml file that I have is exported from the windows machine?
I am working on a Mac though. Can I generate my own .yml file specific to Mac from the given .yml file?

Comment: Also, can I go ahead without importing any .yml file will that be an issue?

Comment: I noticed something which @merv pointed out https://anaconda.org/msys2/m2w64-gmp. It shows this is a windows package, whereas I am installing it on Mac. That could be causing issues. I have a few questions 1.  Do I need to import a .yml file at all to continue with the installation?    2.   Should I find an equivalent package name for Mac and replace it with .yml file   3. For Mac, is the format for the .yml file the same as the one I have pasted?  Thanks a lot